# Android multi module libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How can I build all Android modules in project and expose those to maven repository without creating huge gradle script? There are no clear instructions about modularity in Android projects with artefacts generated by gradle maven plugin. It would be awesome to use built in task.

Answer (score 0):

In few steps:

1. Create a common gradle file in root directory, such as `config.gradle` and put this fragment:

```
ext.packageName = "com.abc.example"

ext.mavenPublisher = {
    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        archiveClassifier.set('sources')
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        publishing {
            publications {
                maven(MavenPublication) {
                    from components.release
                    artifact androidSourcesJar
                    groupId = packageName
                    artifactId = findProperty('moduleName')
                    version = getVersion()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. In root `gradle.properties` add property `version=1.0.0`.
3. In library module `build.gradle` add:

```
apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/config.gradle"

with mavenPublisher
```

4. Also in library module add `gradle.properties` with:

```
moduleName=name
```

5. Type in console from root project directory: `gradle clean build publishToMavenLocal`.

In section `from components.release` you can change release type to `debug` or another one build type. Also you can add version to each module if you want, but probably some release plugin configuration is required.

Working example at [this link](https://github.com/KurdTt/multimodule-android-libraries).